# for scurrilous reasons

Tags: word-choice

(ex) A lot of people have asked John why he wants to write a review of his colleague's latest novel. He's always trying to dodge their questions for scurrilous reasons. However, some people know he has an intention of damaging his colleague's reputation.

Does it make sense to say "scurrilous reasons"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble describing it, but I'd love to know more about the context.
As it stands it sounds like it was generated by a bot. I can't tell how those sentence are related. Each sentence seems *technically* correct, but It is very unclear how they relate to each other.

I'd say that *scurrilous* is the least of this texts problems. When I read each sentence, I think to myself "yeah sure, I think I get the general idea", but I'm not sure how the whole text fits together.

So to answer your question, I don't think that scurrilous makes sense in
this context. I don't think there is any context to make sense of.

Comment: "it sounds like it was generated by a bot." - or a non-native speaker (who, particularly, doesn't understand what 'scurrilous' means, and is too lazy to consult a dictionary).